# Draw a cube with a stroke and fill in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, drawing

I need to draw a load of cubes and would like them to be white with black stroke. At the moment I am storing all of these cubes in a VBO and I can draw them in wireframe and filled with no outline.

I would like to draw them like the image on the left in [this image](http://s13.postimage.org/ywer1kabb/cubes2.jpg), stroked only on the sides facing the camera, not like the right.

I am using OpenGL.

Comment: You should understand that OpenGL has no concept of "fill" and "stroke."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to [remove hidden lines](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter14.html#name16).

> If you want to draw a wireframe object with hidden lines removed, one approach is to draw the outlines using lines and then fill the interiors of the polygons making up the surface with polygons having the background color.

Answer (score 0):

You need to glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE); in order to get back-face culling of triangles not visible automatically applied.  Provided the "winding order" of your triangles is consistent of course (clockwise or anti-clockwise).  If they're wound in the opposite direction, you can tell OpenGL which direction to use with glFrontFrace(GL_CW | GL_CCW) and whether to cull front or back facing triangles with glCullFace(GL_BACK | GL_FRONT).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have numerous cubes infront of each other, so culling backfaces doesn't really work as I have cubes with a front face facing the back face of another cube that's infront of it. In that case the front of the rear cube would need to be culled as well... if that makes any sense.

Comment: If you're drawing them filled (with white fill solid, and outlining the frame, which is what I assumed you'd be doing) then the depth buffer will work as normal.  If not, there's no way to do this with OpenGL.  You have to clip the lines against each other on the CPU.